# GCP unknown activity logs related to VM creation. What could be causing them?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

So I am helping out on a project in Google cloud and recently it has come to my attention that in the "activity" tab, right next to the dashboard on the home page there is a set of logs. My problem is that I am getting a series of logs on repeat with the following order:

1.Create VM

2.Add instances to instance group

3.Remove instances from instance group

4.Delete VM

Also, the actions are being done by a service account.

This project had people working before in it, so I am not aware of everything that has been done in the past. That being said, I am tasked with finding out where this is coming from.

In my search I came up with things like there might have been an managed instance group with load balancer and autoscaler enabled which could be causing the automatic recreation of instances. However, when searching on this section there is nothing on instance groups, load balancers or anything of the like. There aren't even VMs on compute engine.

Any idea on what could be causing it or how I can begin to search for this?

Comment: Can you check is there is keys on the service account that perform these actions? If so, it's possible that is an external process that perform these actions.

Comment: From what I can tell it is a Google API service agent mentioned on [this link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#google-managed). But I don't see any other clues, I think it has no keys also.

Comment: And you haven't instance group or K8S cluster?

Comment: Definitely no instance groups. They show up empty. I have not heard of k8s cluster before, I'll double check but I don't think there is any. I'm wondering if there is any other way to back trace this activity logs, it's really vague and beyond the service account I have no clues

Comment: Do you have a VPC Serverless Connector?